# How to iterarte and add in the object by keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with objects in javascript.

**1.**

```
Units = [
    {
        "BedDetails": [
            {
                "Outpatient": 2,
                "ICU_Beds": 0,
                "NL_Beds": 2,
                "Extra": 9,
                "Ordinary": 3,
                "ADMIN": 6,
                "SVC_Areas": 3.2 // It is different kind not type of bed
            }                  
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "BedDetails": [
            {
                "Outpatient": 4,
                "ICU_Beds":2,                
                "Extra": 2,
                "Ordinary": 2,
                "ADMIN":2,
                "SVC_Areas": 2.1  // It is different kind not type of bed
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I need to perform three operations

1. sum by types of beds
2. If type of bed type is > 0 then sum SVC_Areas as SVC_bedType .
3. ratio of Bed type / SVC_bedtype.

For Ex:

- step 1 is summing bed types
- step 2 is if bedtype > 0 then sum svc under bedtype as below

  `Outpatient > 0  => SVC_outpatient = 2`

  `ICU > 0 => SVC_ICU = 0`        //Here ICU = 0 so summing performed
- Step 3 is ratio of `(sum of bedtype) /  SVC_bedtype`   // obtained in step1/step2

Here is I performed until now

```
Units.forEach(function (element) {               
    var Beds_Details = element.BedDetails[0];                   
    Sum_Outpatient += Beds_Details.Outpatient;
    Sum_ICUBeds += Beds_Details.ICU_Beds;                   
    Sum_Extra += Beds_Details.Extra;
    Sum_Ordinary += Beds_Details.Ordinary;
    Sum_ADMIN += Beds_Details.ADMIN;

    if (Beds_Details.Outpatient > 0) { (SVC_Outpatient += Beds_Details.SVC_Areas).toFixed(2); }
    if (Beds_Details.ICU_Beds > 0) { (SVC_ICUBeds += Beds_Details.SVC_Areas).toFixed(2); }                    
    if (Beds_Details.Extra > 0) { (SVC_Extra += Beds_Details.SVC_Areas).toFixed(2); }
    if (Beds_Details.Ordinary > 0) { (SVC_Ordinary += Beds_Details.SVC_Areas).toFixed(2); }
    if (Beds_Details.ADMIN > 0) { (SVC_ADMIN += Beds_Details.SVC_Areas).toFixed(2); }
});

if (SVC_Outpatient  > 0) { 
   RatioModel_Outpatient  = (Sum_Outpatient  / SVC_Outpatient ).toFixed(2); 
} else { 
         RatioModel_Outpatient = 0; 
       };

if (SVC_ICUBeds > 0) { 
    RatioModel_ICUBeds = (Sum_ICUBeds / SVC_ICUBeds).toFixed(2); 
} else { 
        RatioModel_ICUBeds = 0; 
       };               

if (SVC_Extra  > 0) { 
    RatioModel_EX_TR = (Sum_Extra  / SVC_Extra ).toFixed(2); 
} else { 
          RatioModel_Extra  = 0; 
       };

if (SVC_Ordinary  > 0) { 
    RatioModel_Ordinary  = (Sum_Ordinary  / SVC_Ordinary ).toFixed(2); 
} else { 
            RatioModel_Ordinary  = 0; 
       };

if (SVC_ADMIN > 0) { 
    RatioModel_ADMIN = (Sum_ADMIN / SVC_ADMIN).toFixed(2); 
} else { 
         RatioModel_ADMIN = 0; 
        };
```

Although the code is working fine but i need to optimise the code  by loop through the Bed_details keys.

Can any one help for both the problems

Comment: can you make 2 questions? out of it.  would be easier for you to understand too..

Comment: What you are looking for is `Object.keys(Volume)` but it only returns the keys, you need to make a loop to circle through them and access the needed properties to sum

Comment: Explain your 2nd Question clearly. better be as another qn

Comment: @JinsPeter Question clearly explained. please check

Comment: @charantej where is the bed type?

Comment: @JinsPeter Sorry for misleading you. Bed type is BedDetails in object I said it as a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement as per our chat is implemented here.
You will have your Output in output object.

Find the working fiddle here
[AnswerFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60j7cr1v/3/)

```
var output = {};
function getPropertySum(propertyName){
  var sum = 0;
  Units.forEach(function(obj){
      var item = obj.BedDetails["0"];
      sum =  sum + (item[propertyName]||0);
  });
  return sum;
};
function getPropertySVC(propertyName){
  var svc = 0;
  Units.forEach(function(obj){
    var item = obj.BedDetails["0"];
    if(item[propertyName]>0){
       svc = svc + (item.SVC_Areas||0);
    }
  });
  return parseFloat(svc.toFixed(2));
};

function getPropertyDetails(propertyName){
    var svc = getPropertySVC(propertyName);
    var sum = getPropertySum(propertyName);
    var ratio = svc === 0 ? 0: sum/svc;
    output["Sum_"+ propertyName] = sum;
    output["SVC_"+ propertyName] = svc;
    output["RatioModel_"+ propertyName] = parseFloat(ratio.toFixed(2));

}

var bedItem = Units[0].BedDetails[0];
for(var property in bedItem){
    if(property!=="SVC_Areas"){
            getPropertyDetails(property);
    }  
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanx for all help and answering,one small modification in answer is required. In `var bedItem` u have taken the properties names,now what happens when one property is missing in [0] and present in remaining

Comment: Yeah. I had had seen that. Either you have to include all the properties in BedDetails[0]. or you will have to create a new array to loop through having keyArrray =[ "Outpatient","ICU_Beds",..."ADMIN"].

Comment: @charantej Do you want me to do that too.?? Kindly accept answer and give me a vote?